# ClassCastException when compiling, loading and using inherited class at runtime

Tags: java, classloader, javacompiler

I am trying to compile, load and use an inherited class at runtime. Here is the structure of my Java/Maven project. Note there are no .java files under `com.mycompany.model.inherited`. This is where generated class files will be placed.

```
src/main/java
  com.mycompany.model.base
    BaseClass.java

src/test/java
  com.mycompany.model.inherited
```

BaseClass.java

```java
package com.mycompany.model.base;

public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract void doWork();
}
```

At runtime I write the contents of an inherited class to src/test/java/com/mycompany/inherited/SubClass.java

```
package com.mycompany.model.inherited;

import com.mycompany.model.BaseClass;

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("SubClass is doing work.");
    }
}
```

And then I execute this code to compile SubClass.java, load it, create an object instance. All of that works fine. But when I try to cast it to a BaseClass I'm getting a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Here's the full code.

```
// prepare the class file contents and write it to disk.
String subClassContents =
    "package com.mycompany.model.inherited;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "import com.mycompany.model.base.BaseClass;\n" +
    "\n" +
    "public class SubClass extends BaseClass {\n" +
    "\n" +
    "    @Override\n" +
    "    public void doWork() {\n" +
    "        System.out.println(\"SubClass is doing work.\");\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}\n";
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\com\\mycompany\\model\\inherited\\SubClass.java");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(subClassContents);
writer.close();

// compile the class using the current classpath.
File[] files = new File[]{file};
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager filemanager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable fileObjects = filemanager.getJavaFileObjects(files);
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, null, options, null, fileObjects);
task.call();

// load the class using the current classpath.
String[] paths = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(";");
List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add(new File("src/test/java").toURI().toURL());
for (String p : paths) {
    urls.add(new File(p).toURI().toURL());
}
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls.stream().toArray(URL[]::new));
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.mycompany.model.inherited.SubClass", true, classLoader);

// use the class.
BaseClass base = (BaseClass) cls.newInstance();
base.doWork();
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mycompany.model.inherited.SubClass cannot be cast to com.mycompany.model.base.BaseClass
```

If I include src/test/java/com/mycompany/model/inherited/SubClass.java at compile time it works fine. I.e:

```
BaseClass base = (BaseClass) SubClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.mycompany.model.inherited.SubClass").newInstance();
base.doWork();
```

Hoping someone can point to the issue and help me solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast failed because the base class of `SubClass` is actually considered a different class from the "`BaseClass`" that you wrote in your source code. They are considered different because they are loaded by different class loaders. The base class of `SubClass` is loaded by the `URLClassLoader` you created, whereas the `BaseClass` you wrote in the source code is presumably loaded by the system class loader.

To fix this, you can set the parent class loader of the `URLClassLoader` to the same class loader as the one that loaded `BaseClass`, and only give `src/test/java` as the class path. This way, when the `URLClassLoader` loads `SubClass`, it can't find `BaseClass` in `src/test/java` and so would use the parent class loader to load it.

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
    new URL[] { new File("src/test/java").toURI().toURL() }, 
    BaseClass.class.getClassLoader()
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper for your detailed answer! Adding `BaseClass` to the class loader worked! The `ClassCastException` is no longer occuring!